I'm having trouble trying to read text from a file on a websocket server
I'm trying to read data from a text file on a websocket server that I am hosting locally on a glassfish server, but nothing I've tried so far has gotten it to work.
This is the function I've used to try and read the data
public ArrayList<String> readFromFile (){
        ArrayList <String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        URL wordsURL = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/words/easy.txt");
        File wordFile = null;
        try {
            wordFile = new File(wordsURL.toURI());
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            words.add(e.getMessage());
            return words;`your text`
        }

        Scanner reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new Scanner(wordFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
            words.add(reader.nextLine());
        }

        return words;
    }


Resources are not files. Just use this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream() directly, and wrap the new Scanner around it, and forget about the File.
